# Script for getting last reboot timestamp (2008r2)

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, powershell, powershell-v3.0

I have a list of ad-integrated computers and I need a list of them with their last reboot time. I found some comands like `Get-WmiObject -ClassName win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName xxx | select csname, lastbootuptime` but it's not what I need. I would need a script because there are lots of computers.

I have no experience with PowerShell, if someone could help me with some suggestions.

```
PS C:\Users\XxX> Get-wmiobject win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName LC006909 | select csname, @{label='LastRestart';expression={$_.ConverToDateTime($_.LastBootUpTime)}}

csname                                                      LastRestart
------                                                      -----------
LC006909
```

I get this output ... empty under LastRestart.

Comment: And why is LastBootUpTime not what you want?  It's exactly "their as reboot time".

Comment: It's exactly what i want but i get something like this:                                     csname                                                      lastbootuptime
------                                                      --------------
LC006909                                                    20150916141135.109999+330

Comment: I need a normal time output

Comment: If you're getting a string like `20150916141135.109999+330`, then it's easily parsable into a "normal time output". Just break out the characters into year (2015), month (09), day (16), hour (14), minutes (11), seconds (35), what I assume are milliseconds (109999) and GMT offset (+330).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Nixphoe's** answer is definitely correct, but I want to add on how to get lastbootuptime for the multiple computers (the output can also be redirected to a file if needed):

**Get Last Boot Time for Multiple Machines**

```
$compname = Get-Content -Path C:\computers.txt
foreach ($comp in $compname) {
    Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $comp| select CSName, @{LABEL='LastBootUpTime';EXPRESSION={$_.ConverttoDateTime($_.lastbootuptime)}}

}
```

`C:\computers.txt`  - put computer hostnames one in a row here

Answer (score 4):

For me, systeminfo is really slow. If you have powershell 3, you should be able to use something like

```
Get-CimInstance -ComputerName $yourcomputerObj -ClassName win32_operatingsystem | select csname, lastbootuptime
```

or

```
Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $yourcomputerObj | select csname, @{LABEL='LastBootUpTime';EXPRESSION={$_.ConverttoDateTime($_.lastbootuptime)}}
```

[Link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/03/27/powertip-get-the-last-boot-time-with-powershell.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to get the last boot time:

```
systeminfo | find /i "Boot Time"
```

would do the trick, for example (in human readable format). Be aware of different languages here, in germany for example you would have to grep for "Systemstartzeit".

You could also try (language independent) wmi:

```
wmic os get lastBootUpTime
```

which will give you the Boot time in reversed format (like 20150915100340.494919+120)

Comment: I agree with you but I'm connected on a Domain Controller and need this information on hundreds of computers. A powershell script or command would be more useful.

Comment: change it to `systeminfo /s $computerName |find /i "boot time"`

Answer (score 1):

I always use

```
systeminfo | find "Time"
```

which outputs

`System Boot Time:          16/09/2015, 08:41:28
Time Zone:                 (UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London`